# Clearing the fields after filtering using p:command Button

Tags: jsf

I have a command button in my view called reset and i mentioned it with default attribute called type="reset", this button clears and resets the name Field to the previously entered characters. For Example:
If there is name called "Kios" and i delete it manually on the field but type something else and press reset button, again it is set to Kios.
but if the field is empty previously  and i enter some name and press reset button, its clearing the field to empty.
Here is the code for the View.
Thanks for your suggestions in Advance

```
   <p:commandButton                   type="reset" 
                                   value="Reset" />
```

Comment: What problem you have with it? you haven't mentioned your issue.

Comment: Please, edit your question if you need to explain it better, don't post an answer... unless it's an answer.

Answer (score 0):

The Problem is, when i press the reset button it must be the same page as same as before. [the page which shows list of files and filter dialog.]
There is a initial process.xhtml page,  Image 1 for making a search and a reset button.
If i press the reset Button, i need to get back to main page showing the list of files as before making the search.
I changed the button reset to.